# Recurrence Relation of n-digit quaternary?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Determine the n-digit quaternary (0,1,2,3) sequences in which there is never a 3 anywhere to the right of a zero.

So I know that the answer is $a_{n+1}$ = $3a_{n}$ + $3^n$. I understand why it is $3a_{n}$, because if at the $n+1$ the sequence ends with a 1,2 or 3, then at $a_{n}$ I can have have the choice of 0,1,2, or 3. I just don't understand why I'm suddenly using counting for the $3^n$. Also, when do we use counting when it comes to recurrence relations.

Thanks for any help. Sorry if what I'm asking is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**.  See if you can fill in the dots: an $n+1$-digit sequence of the type you want consists of

- $0$ followed by . . . . . . ; or
- $1,2$ or $3$ followed by . . . . . .

Comment: (0,1,2) can follow the zero and 1,2,or 3 can be followed by (0,1,2,3)

Comment: OK but I meant, can you describe all of the rest of the sequence, not just the next digit.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you're trying to get at. 0,1,2 can follow the zero and at then at that point it is 0, the same situation would appear, but if it's 1 or 2, the digit after the 1 or two, we would have four options, and so on.

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, there cannot be a $3$ **anywhere** to the right of a $0$.  So for example, $013$ is not allowed.

Comment: OH. Yeah, thank you so much. I read the question wrong. Thanks so much!