# Determine the number of $n$-digit quaternary $\{0,1,2,3\}$ sequences $a_n$ in which there is never a $3$ anywhere to the right of a $0$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, mathematica

Determine the number of $n$-digit quaternary $\{0, 1, 2, 3\}$ sequences, $a_n$
in which there is never a $3$ anywhere to the right of a $0$. 20213 is thus a
forbidden string of length 5. What is the initial condition? Formulate the
RR and solve on the computer. How many such strings of length 50 are
there?

Comment: This is not a site for homework service. See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: Consider breaking into cases based on the first position of a $0$ (*including it never occurring*).  Before the first zero there are $3$ options for each digit.  At the first zero, there is one option.  After the first zero, there are $3$ options for each digit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recurrence Relation of n-digit quaternary?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1183329/recurrence-relation-of-n-digit-quaternary)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finishing from the hint I gave earlier... break into cases based on whether a zero appeared or not.

In the case that no zero appeared, every one of the $n$ positions could be any of the digits $\{1,2,3\}$, giving $3^n$ possible sequences.

In the case that a zero does appear, pick the position of the first occurring zero.  There are $n$ options for this.  Next, for all digits left of the first zero, they may be any of the digits $\{1,2,3\}$.  Then, for all digits right of the first zero, they may be any of the digits $\{0,1,2\}$.  In either case it is $3$ options per position in each of the $n-1$ positions giving $3^{n-1}$ possible ways to fill in the remaining positions.

The total number is then:

$$3^n+50\times 3^{n-1}$$

---

Now... if you *insist* on using a recurrence relation even though it is clearly not necessary for this problem (*and indeed, makes it harder rather than easier*), I recommend using the same observation I made above and breaking into two separate sequences.

Let $f(n)$ be the number of valid quaternary sequences of length $n$ where no $0$ appears.  Let $g(n)$ be the number of valid quaternary sequences of length $n$ where a $0$ does appear.

We have initial conditions $f(0)=1$ and $g(0)=0$.  (*Don't forget that the empty sequence is still a sequence.  If that bothers you too much, then we have initial conditions $f(1)=3$ and $g(1)=1$*)

We have $f(n)=3\cdot f(n-1)$ and $g(n)=f(n-1)+3\cdot g(n-1)$

Finally we have the sequence we are actually interested in, the number of valid sequences of length $n$ regardless of whether or not a zero appeared will be $a(n)=f(n)+g(n)$

Comment: Thank you kind sir, i really appriciate you time and effort!

Comment: Is it correct to say that the reccurance relation is aₙ = 3a ₙ-1 + 3 ^ ⁿ-1. And if so what are the initial conditions? Are they as you mentioned a0 = 0?

Comment: @azemi $a_0=1$ not $a_0=0$.  The empty sequence ` ` satisfies the condition of being a length zero sequence with no $3$'s occurring to the right of any $0$'s.  Again, if thinking about sequences of length zero bothers you then use $a_1=4$ as your initial condition.  As for your proposed recurrence relation in the comments... it appears correct, but frustrating to explain.  When building a new sequence of length $n$ we take a valid sequence of length $n-1$ of which there are $a_{n-1}$ many choices and break into cases based on if a $0$ has appeared yet.  If it hadn't, and we want to continue...

Comment: ...not having zeroes, then we have three options for a digit to append, $\{1,2,3\}$.  If a zero *had* appeared, then we have three options for a digit to append $\{0,1,2\}$.  These combined contribute $3a_{n-1}$ to the total.  If we hadn't had a zero appear yet but we want one to start appearing, then there are $3^{n-1}$ ways to do this, giving the overall recurrence $a_n=3a_{n-1}+3^{n-1}$.  Personally, I find this unnatural, and if you were to be able to spot the $3^{n-1}$ term while making the recurrence... then why bother with the recurrence at all and just go with the closed form.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer, very well put. The reasoning for all the extra troubble you've mentioned is because that's the way our teacher wants it, so all we can do is obey, hehe. Yet again thanks alot for your answers they were really helpful.

Best regards.